# Can't add more than one migration with Add-Migration - Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework-core, pomelo-entityframeworkcore-mysql

**Steps to reproduce**

- Have already a migration
- Try to add another one by just using Package Manager Console command => Add-Migration Test
  Or try to add an empty migration

**The issue**
I'm trying to add a new or an empty migration with Package Manager Console command => Add-Migration.
I'm having a null ref exception.

Stacktrace =>

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationsModelDiffer.Initialize(ColumnOperation columnOperation, IColumn column, RelationalTypeMapping typeMapping, Boolean isNullable, IEnumerable`1 migrationsAnnotations, Boolean inline)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationsModelDiffer.InitializeColumnHelper(ColumnOperation columnOperation, IColumn column, Boolean inline)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationsModelDiffer.Diff(IColumn source, IColumn target, DiffContext diffContext)+MoveNext()
   at Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.Migrations.Internal.MySqlMigrationsModelDiffer.MakeStringColumnsRequiredWithoutUnexpectedDefaultValue(IColumn source, IColumn target, IEnumerable`1 migrationOperations)+MoveNext()
   at Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.Migrations.Internal.MySqlMigrationsModelDiffer.SkipRedundantCharSetSpecifyingAlterColumnOperations(IEnumerable`1 migrationOperations)+MoveNext()
   at Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.Migrations.Internal.MySqlMigrationsModelDiffer.PostFilterOperations(IEnumerable`1 migrationOperations)+MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationsModelDiffer.DiffCollection[T](IEnumerable`1 sources, IEnumerable`1 targets, DiffContext diffContext, Func`4 diff, Func`3 add, Func`3 remove, Func`4[] predicates)+MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ConcatIterator`1.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationsModelDiffer.Diff(ITable source, ITable target, DiffContext diffContext)+MoveNext()
   at Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.Migrations.Internal.MySqlMigrationsModelDiffer.PostFilterOperations(IEnumerable`1 migrationOperations)+MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationsModelDiffer.DiffCollection[T](IEnumerable`1 sources, IEnumerable`1 targets, DiffContext diffContext, Func`4 diff, Func`3 add, Func`3 remove, Func`4[] predicates)+MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ConcatIterator`1.MoveNext()
   at Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.Migrations.Internal.MySqlMigrationsModelDiffer.PostFilterOperations(IEnumerable`1 migrationOperations)+MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationsModelDiffer.Sort(IEnumerable`1 operations, DiffContext diffContext)
   at Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.Migrations.Internal.MySqlMigrationsModelDiffer.Sort(IEnumerable`1 operations, DiffContext diffContext)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationsModelDiffer.GetDifferences(IRelationalModel source, IRelationalModel target)
   at Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.Migrations.Internal.MySqlMigrationsModelDiffer.GetDifferences(IRelationalModel source, IRelationalModel target)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Design.MigrationsScaffolder.ScaffoldMigration(String migrationName, String rootNamespace, String subNamespace, String language)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.AddMigration(String name, String outputDir, String contextType, String namespace)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigrationImpl(String name, String outputDir, String contextType, String namespace)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigration.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

**Further technical details**

- MySQL version: 8.0.32 MySQL Community Server
- Operating system: Windows 10 22H2
- Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql version: 7.0.0
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.App version: 6.0

**What have I tried ?**

- I tried changing provider to MySql.Date / MySql.EntityFrameworkCore. It's working but I can no longer save blobs in my database.

I thought about having 2 providers in order to have one managing the structure of the database and another one managing datas.
I also have created an issue on the github of Pomelo => [ticket](https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql/issues/1774)

Comment: Duplicate of https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql/issues/1774

Comment: No way ! That's my issue that you can find on the link "Ticket" that I've added at the end of my message, have you took the time to read it ?, Maybe you would've seen it's the same name that created the issue on the github and the stackoverflow.